# Прилагательные от имён Андрей и Юрик

Tags: грамотная-речь, ономастика

Приемлемо ли говорить *Юрикава ручка, Андреева кружка, Андреевская база* и т.п.
По правилам вроде можно только — *ручка Юрика, кружка Андрея, база Андрея*, но на практике звучит скучно и однообразно, так и хочется употребить 1-й вариант.

Comment: Почему «Юрик»? Полное — скучно и однообразно?

Comment: Почему бы и не Юрик? Может, это Юрик Варданян?

Comment: Друга называть Юрий?)

Comment: Андрей — недруг?

Answer (score 1):

[Розенталь **§164. Употребление притяжательных прилагательных**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/58.htm#%D0%B7_04)

**1) Юрикова ручка, Андреева кружка**

**Сохраняются формы на ОВ/ИН при образовании от личных имен** (Иваново детство, Верины куклы) и в устойчивых фразеологических сочетаниях, закрепившихся в языке (адамово яблоко, антонов огонь, анютины глазки и д.)

2) **Отцово воспитание/ отцовское воспитание:** При выборе вариантов в синонимических конструкциях отцов дом – отцовский дом следует учитывать, что прилагательные на -ский (-овский, -инский) чаще выражают качественное 
значение; ср.: отцовская забота, материнская любовь.

**Андреевская база** (база Андрея) – суффикс СК  не обозначает  притяжательность (принадлежность), поэтому нет точности выражения, соответственно, стиль разговорно-просторечный. **Андреевская церковь** (в честь Андрея) – относительное прилагательное.

Answer (score 0):

Юрик**о**ва ручка, Андреева кружка (не Андреевская). Но: отцов ремень и отцовский ремень — оба варианта верны.

Comment: Тогда почему в Киеве есть Андреевская церковь? Воздвигнутая в честь Андрея Первозванного.

Comment: Андреевская - названная в честь Андрея, Андреева - принадлежащая Андрею

Comment: «Простите, а что значит выделенная о?» – Aer♦ ========== В вопросе вначале была другая буква.